# Error on response from webService to IE

Tags: javascript, web-services, internet-explorer

i'm usig this script below, and works perfectly on chrome, and firefox, but on ie, i can't get the response from webservice. I need open/redirect to anothers sites if success or error! Why can read response from webservice on IE, and how resolve this?

```
function sendInfo(userId, Code) {
// text with all info to send to controller
var values = {
    "token": Code,
    "code": userId
}

// POST THE CHANGE HERE TO THE DATABASE
var url = "WSFacebook.asmx/saveToken";
$.post(url, values, function(data) {

            if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                return data.xml;
            }
            var xmlString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);
            var xml = xmlString,
                xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
                $xml = $(xmlDoc),
                $title = $xml.find("string");
            var texto = $title.text();
            if ($title.text() == "Success") {
                window.location = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["successUrl"].ToString() %>';
            } else {
                window.location = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["errorUrl"].ToString() %>';
            }
    });
```

}

Comment: You have some IE specific code in there. `window.ActiveXObject`. Currently, in IE this will not parse the xml as it would in other browsers. Is that your error?

Comment: i don't have no errors on ie, only not entry on 'function(data)', because i'm try(for exemple) put the windows.location on begin of 'function(data) and do nothing, but if i put the windows.location on end of script 'sendInfo', just call the redirect.

Comment: Well no matter what, that `return data.xml;` statement is pointless. Nothing is going to pay any attention to the return value from that handler function.